# Replace line with multi-line file

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to replace a line with a multi-line file.  I can easily do this with a single-line file or multi-line string (see below).

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW_STRING="apple\nbanana\ncarrot"

sed -i "3s/.*/$(echo "${NEW_STRING}")/" tmp.txt

# Outputs...
# line 1
# line 2
# apple
# banana
# carrot
# line 4
# line 5
# ...
# etc
```

However, when I change the code to use a multi-file, such as `replace.txt`, I receive the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
```

**broken_script.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=`cat replace.txt`

sed -i "3s/.*/$(echo "${FILE}")/" tmp.txt
```

**replace.txt**

```
++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  apple size=8, align=2, ..., etc.
  banana size=64, align=8, ..., etc.
  ...
  carrot size=92, align=4, ..., etc.
```

Note `broken_script.bash` works if I delete `replace.txt` to be a single-line (i.e. just `++++`).

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Why doesn't this work with a multi-line file as the replacement text (i.e. like the single-line file or multi-line string)?

Comment: Is there a `/` anywhere in `replace.txt`? Also, instead of `s///`, you could look into the `r` command, or `c`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. There are no `/` characters in replace.txt.

Comment: This is a great use case for `r`.  eg `sed  '3rreplace.txt' tmp.txt`

Comment: To also delete the 3rd line, do `sed -e '3rreplace.txt' -e 3d tmp.txt`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's great! You should write an answer. Maybe you could even explain why `3d;3rfile` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace lines with the contents of a file, you can use the `r` command:

```
sed -e 3rreplace.txt -e 3d tmp.txt
```

As asked in a comment, `sed -e 3d -e 3rreplace.txt` does not work because the `d` command immediately returns to the top of the program after reading the next line and never executes the `r` command.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all:** Drop the `echo` part. You can use the variable directly.

**Back to the actual problem:**
The difference is how you encode the newline. In the first command you wrote `\n` do denote a newline. That `\n` is not interpreted by 'bash', but directly sent to `sed`. In the second command, the file content is sent to `sed`, including literal newline characters. For a file with the two lines `line1` and `line2` the command `sed` sees is

```
3s/.*/line1
line2/
```

`sed` cannot handle such multi-lined commands.

**Non-sed solution:**
As it seems, you just want to replace the third line of one file with the content of another file. This can be done with

```
cat <(head -n 2 file1) file2 <(tail -n +4 file1)
```

`head -n2 file1` prints the first two lines of `file1`.
`tail -n +4 file 1` prints all lines of `file1` starting at line 4.
`<(command)` is called *process substitution* and emulates a file containing the output of `command`.
`cat` concatenates the three "files".

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can do this with some quote juggling

```
$ seq 5 | sed -e '/3/{r replace.txt' -e 'd}'

1
2
++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  apple size=8, align=2, ..., etc.
  banana size=64, align=8, ..., etc.
  ...
  carrot size=92, align=4, ..., etc.
4
5
```

for in place replacement you need to provide file

```
$ sed -i -e '/3/{r replace.txt' -e 'd}' file
```

of course test first or take backup.